# Adding other variables with key and value and appending of a dict to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to pass columns from a dataframe to a function which in return provides a dictionary, that needs to be appended in the same dataframe in 2 columns result and cost.

For example the function is:

```
    def costsplit (acc, srv, owner, cost):
           
        test = splitter().split(acc, srv, owner, cost)
               
        return test
```

Suppose dictionary type of data being return by test for dev is `test = {'dps':32, 'dd':21, 'ct':92, 'cc':32}`.

It means `{'dps':32, 'dd':21, 'ct':92, 'cc':32}` is being returned by test when `acc = dev, srv = instance owner = dpc is cost =30` is passed i.e. row 1 of below dataframe, same some other output `{'dps':20, 'dd':21, 'ct':92, 'cc':2}` is being returned by test when `acc = prd, srv = instance, owner = abs, cost =35` is passed i.e. row 4 and they are getting appended in the result and cost column in dataframe.

The current dataframe looks  like:

```
    date         acc  srv         owner    result         cost
    
    2021-03-01   dev   bucket      dps      gcp.dev.dps       177
    2021-03-01   prd   instance    abs       gcp.prd.abs      35
    2021-03-01   dev   spanner      cc      gcp.dev.cc       98
    2021-03-01   prd   instance        it    gcp.prd.it     135
```

Now the output dataframe should append into the `result` and `cost` columns from the dictionary key-value pair.

The output should be like:

```
    date         acc  srv         owner    result         cost
    
    2021-03-01   dev   bucket      dps      gcp.dev.dps       177
    2021-03-01   prd   instance    abs       gcp.prd.abs      35
    2021-03-01   dev   spanner      cc      gcp.dev.cc        98
    2021-03-01   prd   instance    it        gcp.prd.it       135
    2021-03-01                              gcp.dev.dps       32
    2021-03-01                              gcp.dev.dd        21
    2021-03-01                               gcp.dev.ct       92
    2021-03-01                               gcp.dev.cc       32
    2021-03-01                              gcp.prd.dps       20
    2021-03-01                              gcp.prd.dd        21
    2021-03-01                               gcp.prd.ct       92
    2021-03-01                               gcp.prd.cc       2
```

i.e. loop runs on each row of current dataframe for `acc, srv, owner, cost` column data being passed to `costsplit` function should get appended with each `gcp.{acc}.{testkey}` in the `result` section and `test` value gets added to the `cost` column which are being returned by `test`.

The `splitter().split` function is dividing the cost and renaming the owner based on each row that is being sent from the dataframe.

With the below command I am only able to append `result` function, not the `cost` one.

```
    acc['result'] = acc.apply(lambda x: [f'gcp.{acc}.{squ}' for squ, cost in test.items()], axis=1)
```

Comment: How do you convert `{'dps':32, 'dd':21, 'ct':92, 'cc':32}` to the values you expect in the result column? Why does `dps` translate to `gcp.dev.dps` while `dd` translates to `gcp.sandbox.dd`?

Comment: @Mortz it is because dps has ```acc dev```  when ```costsplit``` function is being passed. while for dd the recurring could take place in sandbox. main point is ```gcp.{acc}.{test.key}``` this type of format should form for ```result``` column, where acc is the account for which the function ran, gcp is fixed and test.key is the key for that row acc output.

Comment: @Mortz so result is getting appended for all the rows from the dataframe being passed simultaneously for acc srv and owner and cost.

Comment: @Mortz I have made some changes in the question might help you give more insight into the question. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understood everything correctly.

But I want to suggest a solution-in-progress. Tell me what was communicated unclear and we will figure it out together. :-)

```
import pandas as pd

COST_DICT = {
    "bucket": {"dev": {"dps": 177}},
    "spanner": {"dev": {"cc": 98}},
    "instance": {
        "prd": {"dps": 20, "dd": 21, "ct": 92, "cc": 2, "it": 135, "abs": 35},
        "dev": {"dps": 32, "dd": 21, "ct": 92, "cc": 32},
    },
}


def costsplit(acc, srv, owner, previous_cost):
    add_cost = COST_DICT[srv][acc][owner]
    result = f"gcp.{acc}.{owner}"
    cost = previous_cost + add_cost
    return pd.Series({"result": result, "cost": cost})


acc_content = {
    "date": ["2021-03-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-01"],
    "acc": ["dev", "prd", "dev", "prd"],
    "srv": ["bucket", "instance", "spanner", "instance"],
    "owner": ["dps", "abs", "cc", "it"],
    "prev_cost": [0, 0, 0, 0],
}

acc_first = pd.DataFrame(acc_content)
acc_first[["result", "cost"]] = acc_first.apply(
    lambda row: costsplit(row["acc"], row["srv"], row["owner"], row["prev_cost"]), axis=1
)

#          date  acc       srv owner  prev_cost       result  cost
# 0  2021-03-01  dev    bucket   dps          0  gcp.dev.dps   177
# 1  2021-03-01  prd  instance   abs          0  gcp.prd.abs    35
# 2  2021-03-01  dev   spanner    cc          0   gcp.dev.cc    98
# 3  2021-03-01  prd  instance    it          0   gcp.prd.it   135
```

I don't understand why your output dataframe is empty in the columns `acc, srv, owner`. Didn't you say, that you want to loop through the rows, using these columns to create `result` and overwrite `cost`?
What made the most sense to me according to your explanation:

```
acc_content = {
    "date": [
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
        "2021-03-01",
    ],
    "acc": ["dev", "dev", "dev", "dev", "prd", "prd", "prd", "prd"],
    "srv": ["instance", "instance", "instance", "instance", "instance", "instance", "instance", "instance"],
    "owner": ["dps", "dd", "ct", "cc", "dps", "dd", "ct", "cc"],
    "prev_cost": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}


acc_second = pd.DataFrame(acc_content)

acc_second[["result", "cost"]] = acc_second.apply(
    lambda row: costsplit(row["acc"], row["srv"], row["owner"], row["prev_cost"]), axis=1
)

#          date  acc       srv owner  prev_cost       result  cost
# 0  2021-03-01  dev  instance   dps          0  gcp.dev.dps    32
# 1  2021-03-01  dev  instance    dd          0   gcp.dev.dd    21
# 2  2021-03-01  dev  instance    ct          0   gcp.dev.ct    92
# 3  2021-03-01  dev  instance    cc          0   gcp.dev.cc    32
# 4  2021-03-01  prd  instance   dps          0  gcp.prd.dps    20
# 5  2021-03-01  prd  instance    dd          0   gcp.prd.dd    21
# 6  2021-03-01  prd  instance    ct          0   gcp.prd.ct    92
# 7  2021-03-01  prd  instance    cc          0   gcp.prd.cc     2
```

Points to discuss:

1. the test-dicts you gave were only for `acc=dev, acc=prd`, are there other options?
2. the test-dicts were only for `srv=instance`, but your first df also contains bucket and spanner. I added the information to the cost dictionary, please check.
3. I needed to add values for `abs` and `it` to `COST_DICT["instance"]["prd"]`, in order to make it work for the first dataframe.
4. Please explain again what the output is.

Comment: Thanks. for acc there are other values as well not only dev and prd. same goes for srv = instance, I am not bothered about other columns in the output only result and cost column should be filled. costsplit function is returning a dictionary i.e. a key value pair who's key should be going to result and value to cost

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your comments correctly, you need the `acc` passed into the `costsplit` function for generating the keys. For this, you can define a new `costsplit` function that wraps the existing one -

```
def new_costsplit (acc, srv, owner, cost):           
    test = costsplit(acc, srv, owner, cost)
    return {f'gcp.{acc}.{k}': v for k, v in test.items()}
```

And use this new function for getting your `test_returns` -

```
test_returns = new_costsplit(acc, srv, owner, cost)
```

And then, you can convert the output of the `test_returns` into a `DataFrame` -

```
import pandas as pd
test_returns = {'dps':32, 'dd':21, 'ct':92, 'cc':32}
test_returns = {f'gcp.dev.{k}': v for k, v in test_returns.items()}
test_returns_df = pd.DataFrame({'result': list(test_returns.keys()), 'cost': list(test_returns.values())})
test_returns_df.index = df.index
test_returns_df
#                     result  cost
#    date                         
#    2021-03-01  gcp.dev.dps    32
#    2021-03-01   gcp.dev.dd    21
#    2021-03-01   gcp.dev.ct    92
#    2021-03-01   gcp.dev.cc    32
```

and then append it to your original `DataFrame` -

```
df_new = pd.concat([df, test_returns_df], axis=0)
df_new = df_new.fillna("")
df_new
#                acc cost owner          result       srv
#date                                                    
#2021-03-01      dev   30   dps     gcp.dev.dps    bucket
#2021-03-01      prd   35   abs     gcp.prd.abs  instance
#2021-03-01      dev   98    cc      gcp.dev.cc   spanner
#2021-03-01  sandbox   94    it  gcp.sandbox.it   bigdata
#2021-03-01            32           gcp.dev.dps          
#2021-03-01            21            gcp.dev.dd          
#2021-03-01            92            gcp.dev.ct          
#2021-03-01            32            gcp.dev.cc
```

Comment: if you notice only dev is not being appended to the test output but the acc column name relevant to the row whose data is being passed to the function. so appending gcp.dev afterwards will not work